# Issue between user control and Visual webpart

Tags: visual-web-part, user-controls, custom-masterpage

I have user control in my master page (countrycontrol.ascx) on clicking the user control It will show links, user is allowed to select the country based on the selected country the visual webpart need to render i am storing the selected country in hidden field which is available in the master page. while the visual WP loaded it need two time to change the country then only its refected.

Comment: Could you please explain it with some codE?